# python3 EOFError after loop operation,there is exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

the following is my python 3 code, at line 7 i got a error exception as the following, is there anyone can help me?
thanks in advance

```
Exception Name: EOFError
Exception Message: EOF when reading a line
Exception Line number: 7
5     B = []
6     C = []
7     A = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
8     B = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
9     for index in range(N):
```

I change my code like this, because if one of the list is null, there will be an exception

```
def sum_c(arr):
    for index_C in arr:
        if index_C != arr[-1]:
            print(index_C, end=' ')
        else:
            print(index_C)


N = int(input())
while N != 0:
    A = []
    B = []
    A = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
    B = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
    if len(A) == 0 and len(B) != 0:
        sum_c(B)
    elif len(A) != 0 and len(B) == 0:
        sum_c(A)
    else:
        sum_c([sum(x) for x in zip(A, B)])
    N -= 1
```

Comment: Line `7` is just fine, granted you're indeed using Python 3. Instead of providing the exception details as you did, please provide it in the same way Python does.

Comment: @JimFasarakisHilliard OP probably used some external shell, like iPython. they usually report errors with that format

Comment: In Pycharm there is no exception, but in hackerrank oline programming with python3.5.2 compiler, it will have this exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program expected input when `input()` was called, but the provided stdin had reached its end (or probably was empty).

You simply did not provide input.

Comment: I test it just now in pycharm, after input the first array, i enter but input nothing, then input enter and input the second array, there will be exception.like this condition, how we should solve this problem?